# current in resistor in series with voltage and current sources?

Tags: current, resistors, current-source, voltage-source

[image]

What would be the current in the 3 ohm resistor next to 45v source?

Im not sure if it should be 45/3 or 5 amps!

Comment: Any simulator could tell you.

Comment: could you link me to a simulator? I've searched through multiple ones but always find them too complicated and get stuck when adding the power sources

Answer (score 3):

Since it's in series with the 5A independent current source, I'm going with 5A